# JS Canvas, images in animation stack instead of change after every turn

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, animation, canvas

I have been stuck on this for a few days, and can't find a solution. What I am trying to make is that after every cycle the images change, and after all images get displayed in order it starts again with the first image again. Now the problem I have is that the images on the right get stacked up. Here is the code:

```js
var canvas, ctx, x, y, w, e;
var brojac = 0;
var i = 0;

var images = [];
    images[0] = new Image();
    images[0].src = "https://www.a1smallbusinessmarketing.com/images/prosbo_hires.jpg";
    images[1] = new Image();
    images[1].src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Wiktionary_small.svg/350px-Wiktionary_small.svg.png";
    images[2] = new Image();
    images[2].src ="http://www.jasonjsmith.com/img/small-business-seo.jpg";
    images[3] = new Image();
    images[3].src ="https://g.twimg.com/business/page/image/11TwitterForSmallBusiness-300_1.png";


function start_canvas() {
  function draw() {
    for (i = 0; i <= brojac; i++) {
      if (brojac == 4) {
        brojac = 0;
        i = 0;
      } else {
        ctx.drawImage(images[i], x, y);
      }
    }
  };
  function draw1(w, e) {
    ctx.drawImage(images[i - 1], w, e);
  };


  function update(time) {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (w >= x) {
      e += 8;
      y += 8;
    } else {
      x -= 4;
      w += 4;
    };
    draw(x, y);
    draw1(w, e);

    if (e > canvas.height) {
      brojac++;
      x = canvas.width - 190;
      y = 15;
      w = 1;
      e = 15;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update)

  }
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

  x = canvas.width - 190;
  y = 15;
  w = 1;
  e = 15;


  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  requestAnimationFrame(update)

}
window.addEventListener("load", start_canvas);
```

```css
<style> canvas {
  border: #666 2px solid;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas1" width="1650" height="825" style="width: 650px; height: 330px;"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

*Due to the images I randomly found on the net, the stacking can only be seen with the last two images. How can I make them not stack?
**Side question** If I wanted to make,lets say, images [0,1] from array only go to the middle and not drop, could I use switch statement or should I use if?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your draw function makes no sense to me, why do you have a loop there? You seem to be drawing multiple times

Comment: First loop, brojac is 0, only the first image is drawn, second loop, brojac is 1, so both the first and second images are drawn, repeat until brojac resets to 0 once it hits 4. I think juvian is right here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use (%) modulo to cycle

If you want to cycle through an array of items you can use % to get the array index. % returns the remainder of a divide. ie `0 % 4 == 0`, `3 % 4 == 3`, `4 % 4 == 0`, `7 % 4 == 3`

[Modulo (aka remainder) operator MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())

So if you have an array of items you just create a index and use the array length to get the remainder.

```
 var currentIndex = 0;
 // then to loop through the array
 currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % array.length;
```

Which is very handy and saves us from having to add conditional statements for cycling through arrays and similar.

I rewrote your code. I draw the images in the update loop, i check if the image has loaded though the animation will still play if the image has not loaded. If you move the `if(images[currentImage].complete){` to the beginning of the update function and the closing brace to the line above `requestAnimationFrame...` the animation will not start until the image has loaded.

```js
// image names 
var imageURLS = [
    "https://www.a1smallbusinessmarketing.com/images/prosbo_hires.jpg",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Wiktionary_small.svg/350px-Wiktionary_small.svg.png",
    "http://www.jasonjsmith.com/img/small-business-seo.jpg",
    "https://g.twimg.com/business/page/image/11TwitterForSmallBusiness-300_1.png"
]
// load the images
var images = imageURLS.map(url=>{var img = new Image(); img.src = url; return img});

function start_canvas() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width=1650;
    canvas.height=825;
    canvas.style.width = "650px"; // Note the canvas is scaled down
    canvas.style.height = "330px";
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');    
    var currentImage = 0; // points to the current image being rendered
    const imageStartY = 15;  // constants for image start and speeds
    const imageStartRight = canvas.width - 190;
    const imageStartLeft = 1;
    const horizontalSpeed = 4;
    const verticalSpeed = 8;
    var leftImg = {x : imageStartLeft,y : imageStartY};  // left and right image locations
    var rightImg = {x : imageStartRight,y : imageStartY};    
    // main loop
    function update(time) {  
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        if (leftImg.x >= rightImg.x) { // check if moving down
            leftImg.y += verticalSpeed;
            rightImg.y += verticalSpeed;
        } else {  // else moving towards center
            leftImg.x += horizontalSpeed;
            rightImg.x -= horizontalSpeed;
        };
        if(images[currentImage].complete){ // make sure the current image has loaded
            ctx.drawImage(images[currentImage],leftImg.x, leftImg.y); // draw both images
            ctx.drawImage(images[currentImage],rightImg.x, rightImg.y);
        }
        if (leftImg.y > canvas.height) { // if at bottom cycle to next image and start again
            currentImage = (currentImage + 1) % images.length; // loop image index % is modulo and returns the remainder 
            leftImg.x = imageStartLeft;
            leftImg.y = imageStartY;
            rightImg.x = imageStartRight;
            rightImg.y = imageStartY;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
window.addEventListener("load", start_canvas);
```

Comment: Thank you a bunch for taking your time to show me this. I just have one question, how does this part "url=>" work?

Comment: @JV that is called an Arrow function new to ES6. You can replace it with `function(url){...` The `=>` means that the arguments on the left `url` are passed to the function on the right.`args => function` If you have more than one argument on the left you need brackets eg `(arg1,arg2) => ` if you have more than one statement on the right (normally separated by `;`) you need to put curly braces around them `{ do something; and some morel; }`  and there a more rules. Look it up "Arrow functions"  as its very handy